# Spring Boot @ConditionalOnMissingBean and generic types

Tags: java, spring, generics

Is there any way to get both of these beans instantiated:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public Container<Book> bookContainer() {
    return new Container<>(new Book());
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public Container<Computer> computerContainer() {
    return new Container<>(new Computer());
}
```

`@ConditionalOnMissingBean` only takes the bean class into account, falsely making `bookContainer` and `computerContainer` the same type, thus only one of them gets registered.

I could give explicit qualifiers to each, but since this is a part of a Spring Boot Starter, it would make it annoying to use, as the user would then be forced to somehow know the exact name to override instead of the type only.

**Potential approach:**

Since it is possible to ask Spring for a bean by its full generic type, I might be able to implement a conditional factory that will try to get a fully-typed instance and produce one if it doesn't already exist. I'm now investigating if/how this can be done.
Amazingly, when implementing a custom condition (to be used with `@Conditional`), it does not have access to the bean type...

While every other modern injection framework operates on full types, Spring somehow still works with raw classes and string names(!) which just blows my mind... Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: have you tried to set its name parameter

Comment: @neo You're right, I could. But this is a part of a Spring Boot Starter, so explicit names would make it annoying to use, as the user would then be forced to somehow know the exact name to override instead of the type only. Updated the question with this info.

Comment: When implementing a custom condition,the underlying implementation of class `@AnnotatedTypeMetadata`  is actually `@StandardMethodMetadata`.which has a public method named `#getIntrospectedMethod`,then you can get the reference of  the corresponding method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible since Spring Boot v2.1.0.

That version introduced the new field `parameterizedContainer` on `ConditionalOnMissingBean`.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = Book.class, parameterizedContainer = Container.class)
public Container<Book> bookContainer() {
    return new Container<>(new Book());
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = Computer.class, parameterizedContainer = Container.class)
public Container<Computer> computerContainer() {
    return new Container<>(new Computer());
}
```

Comment: But what should I write if parameter is also generic, e.g. `Container<List<Book>>`?

Comment: I've just read the documentation for this field and this is not the "generic type" support. It's literally the support for bean-wrapping containers, so if the context contains a bean of type `Book` the condition in this answer would fail. Just leaving this info here for those who are looking for generic type support, not the bean containers.

Comment: Just leaving it here, for those wondering if there there will be generics support or not here's the open PR (no updates since Feb'22): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/29500

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Spring now supports this natively. See the accepted answer.

**Original answer:**
Here's a fully working solution. I gave up on this approach, but I'm posting it in case someone finds it useful.

I made a custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Conditional(MissingGenericBeanCondition.class)
public @interface ConditionalOnMissingGenericBean {

    Class<?> containerType() default Void.class;
    Class<?>[] typeParameters() default {};
}
```

And a custom condition to go with it:

```
public class MissingGenericBeanCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        if (!metadata.isAnnotated(ConditionalOnMissingGenericBean.class.getName()) || context.getBeanFactory() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Map<String, Object> attributes = metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(ConditionalOnMissingGenericBean.class.getName());
        Class<?> containerType = (Class<?>) attributes.get("containerType");
        Class<?>[] typeParameters = (Class<?>[]) attributes.get("typeParameters");

        ResolvableType resolvableType;
        if (Void.class.equals(containerType)) {
            if (!(metadata instanceof MethodMetadata) || !metadata.isAnnotated(Bean.class.getName())) {
                throw error();
            }
            //When resolving beans within the starter
            if (metadata instanceof StandardMethodMetadata) {
                resolvableType = ResolvableType.forType(((StandardMethodMetadata) metadata).getIntrospectedMethod().getGenericReturnType());
            } else {
                //When resolving beans in an application using the starter
                MethodMetadata methodMeta = (MethodMetadata) metadata;
                try {
                    // This might not be a safe thing to do. See the notes below.
                    Class<?> declaringClass = ClassUtils.forName(methodMeta.getDeclaringClassName(), context.getClassLoader());
                    Type returnType = Arrays.stream(declaringClass.getDeclaredMethods())
                            .filter(m -> m.isAnnotationPresent(Bean.class))
                            .filter(m -> m.getName().equals(methodMeta.getMethodName()))
                            .findFirst().map(Method::getGenericReturnType)
                            .orElseThrow(MissingGenericBeanCondition::error);
                    resolvableType = ResolvableType.forType(returnType);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    throw error();
                }
            }
        } else {
            resolvableType = ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(containerType, typeParameters);
        }

        String[] names = context.getBeanFactory().getBeanNamesForType(resolvableType);
        return names.length == 0;
    }

    private static IllegalStateException error() {
        return new IllegalStateException(ConditionalOnMissingGenericBean.class.getSimpleName()
                + " is missing the explicit generic type and the implicit type can not be determined");
    }
}
```

These allow me to do the following:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingGenericBean
public Container<Book> bookContainer() {
    return new Container<>(new Book());
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingGenericBean
public Container<Computer> computerContainer() {
    return new Container<>(new Computer());
}
```

Both beans will now be loaded as they're of different generic types. If the user of the starter would register another bean of `Container<Book>` or `Container<Computer>` type, then the default bean would not be loaded, exactly as desired.

As implemented, it is also possible to use the annotation this way:

```
@Bean
//Load this bean only if Container<Car> isn't present
@ConditionalOnMissingGenericBean(containerType=Container.class, typeParameters=Car.class)
public Container<Computer> computerContainer() {
    return new Container<>(new Computer());
}
```

**Notes:**
Loading the configuration class in the condition might not be safe, but in this specific case it also might be... I have no clue. Didn't bother investigating further as I settled on a different approach altogether (different interface for each bean). If you have any info on this, please comment.

If explicit types are provided in the annotation, e.g.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingGenericBean(containerType=Container.class, typeParameters=Computer.class)
public Container<Computer> computerContainer() {
    return new Container<>(new Computer());
}
```

this concern goes away, but this approach will not work if the type parameters are also generic, e.g. `Container<List<Computer>>`.

Another way to make this certainly safe would be to accept the declaring class in the annotation:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingGenericBean(declaringClass=CustomConfig.class)
```

and then use that instead of

```
Class<?> declaringClass = ClassUtils.forName(methodMeta.getDeclaringClassName(), context.getClassLoader());
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any workaround for this?

Unfortunately, I think not. The problem is that generics in Java do not exist in the compiled bytecode - they are used only for type checking at compile time and they only exist in the source code. Therefore at runtime, when Spring Boot sees your bean configuration class, it only sees two bean definitions that both create a Container. It does not see any difference between them unless you provide it yourself by giving them identifiers.

Comment: This isn't really true... While the generic info is lost on the instances, it is very much still present in the method's return type, arguments types etc. See `Method#getGenericReturnType` for an example of what I mean. So Spring _does_ have access to the bean's full type by looking at the full generic type of the method that produced it. CDI and other frameworks make use of this too. And it normally works in Spring too, the problem is with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` in this case.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765205/294657) for a workaround I came up with...