# How to specify a `@ConditionalOnBean` for a bean of type `Map<K, V>`?

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics

How can I specify a `@ConditionalOnBean` for a bean of type `Map<K, V>`? The following code gives a `Cannot access class object of parameterized type` error.

```java
  // ...

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnBean({ Map<String, MyClass>.class })
  public MyService myClassMapBean(Map<String, MyClass> map) {
    return MyService.of(map);

  }
  
  // ...
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at this? It seems to suggest a parameterizedContainer and value that might be able to be applied in your situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/60659022/16034206