# Spring-Boot @ConditionalOnMissingBean on generic class with multiple types

Tags: spring, spring-boot, generics

### The Problem

In our Spring-Boot-Stater Project (Spring-Boot 3.2.3) we have a default Converter Bean. For Simplicity lets say it Converts Integer to String. As it is good Practice we annotated the Bean with @ConditionalOnMissingBean.
The Bean gets Initialized Correctly and may be Exchanged for another Implementation w/o any Problem. **But**, if we create a Converter Bean for some other Types, i.e. Foo to Baa, the default bean is not created and when we try to Inject it, we receive aa UnsatisfiedDependencyException.

When updating the @ConditionalOnMissingBean with type-information as mentioned in [Spring Boot @ConditionalOnMissingBean and generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746148/spring-boot-conditionalonmissingbean-and-generic-types), the Application no longer starts with a IllegalStateException.

### Examples

##### The Default Converter in the spring-boot-starter

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(parameterizedContainer = Converter.class, value={Integer.class, String.class})
public Converter<Integer,String> exampleConverter() {
    return Integer::toHexString;
}
```

##### replace converter

```
@Bean
Converter<Integer, String> exampleConverter() {
    return Integer::toBinaryString;
}
```

##### Some Other Converter in the Project

```
@Bean
Converter<String, String> uppercaseConverter() {
    return String::toUpperCase;
}
```

#### Workaround

The none ideal option we currently use is to restrict the bean by name.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "exampleConverter")
public Converter<Integer,String> exampleConverter() {
    return Integer::toHexString;
}
```

### The Question

So, we found a workaround but this is not Ideal. The actual Question is, am I doing something wrong with the generic conditions or is this a Bug in Spring-Boot and I should file a Issue on GitHub?

##### Error Log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on io.d4e.starter.ExampleAutoConfiguration.exampleConverter
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1454) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:142) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:98) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:383) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:290) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:279) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:63) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched number of generics specified for public abstract interface org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<S,T>
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:129) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(ResolvableType.java:1125) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(ResolvableType.java:1111) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:249) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> am I doing something wrong with the generic conditions or is this a Bug in Spring-Boot and I should file a Issue on GitHub?

It's definitelly not a bug. I'm afraid you're slightly misinterpreting the `value` parameter in the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation. The ability to add multiple classes to the `value` parameter is used to add multiple conditions for the existence of a given Bean type.

For example, creating an annotation like this:

```java
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(parameterizedContainer = Converter.class, value={Integer.class, String.class})
```

Spring understands as: "Create a Bean if there is neither a Bean of type `Converter<Integer>` nor a Bean of type `Converser<String>`".

The `parameterizedContainer` parameter was created to define Generic Beans with only one generic type. I'm afraid there is no out-of-the-box solution to what you want to achieve and the only solution is to use `org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition` from the Stack Overflow thread you've linked in your question.

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27410#issuecomment-899711749

> The parameterizedContainer attribute was primarily added to support classes like ServletRegistrationBean bean. The idea being that we'd detect beans of a specific type or their wrapper. For example, MyServlet or ServletRegistrationBean would both match a @ConditionalOnBean(value=MyServlet.class, parameterizedContainer=ServletRegistrationBean.class).
> It looks like you are trying to do something slightly different. I'm guessing you want to register the PersonToPepUserConverter only if a Converter<Person, User> bean is missing. There's no out-of-the-box condition annotation to do that I'm afraid. You might be able to write your own Condition that calls beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType with a different ResolvableType.
> (...)